# Prove Probability of Two Continuous Random Variables Equal is 0?

Tags: statistics, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I'm in a formal statistics class and it is driving me crazy. Here's the problem, I'm given that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent random variables uniformly distributed on $[0, \theta]$. I'm being asked to show that $P(X_1 = X_2) = 0$. Obviously, I can see that this is true, so I'm trying to figure out what I'm even being expected to prove.

I'm provided with the hint $P(X_1 = X_2) =  E[1_{X_1=X_2}] = 1/\theta^2\int_{[0,\theta]^2}1_{x_1=x_2}dx_2dx_2$.

I assume the 2nd part of the hint is because $E[1_{X_1=X_2}] = \int_{\mathbb{R}^2}1_{X_1=X_2}dP(X_1,X_2)$ where the notation $dP(X_1, X_2)$ basically refers to the joint PDF of $X_1$ and $X_2$ (which for some reason we now instead refer to as the probability measure of $X_1$ and $X_2$), which gives us the $1/\theta^2$ term.

But from here I'm confused. What exactly do I do to prove that $\int_{[0,\theta]^2}1_{x_1=x_2}dx_2dx_2 = 0$? Is there some way to break it into a standard double integral? I think the problem is that I basically have no idea how to evaluate Lebesgue integrals except by turning them into some combination of Reimann integrals and then evaluating those, and in this case there seems to be no obvious way of doing so.

Comment: Hint:  Calculate the probability two values are in an interval, then take the limit of that interval going to a single point.

Comment: Is the idea here to make use of the fact that, for lebesgue integrals, we can move limits from outside the integral inside the integral and vice-versa?

Comment: Yes... that is one way to view the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

The double integral is
$$ \int_0^\theta dx_1 \int_0^\theta dx_2 \; 1_{x_1=x_2} $$

But $$\int_0^\theta dx_2 \; 1_{x_1=x_2} = \int_0^\theta dx_2\; 0 = 0$$ 
because changing an integrand at a single point never changes the integral.

Comment: I'm confused, how can I move the indicator function outside the integral, aren't I only allowed to bring things outside the integral that are not functions of either $x_1$ and $x_2$? And isn't this indicator function a function of both? And once I do so, I'm not sure why I can just set it equal to 0.

Comment: I didn't bring anything outside the integral.  I evaluated the inner integral (at arbitrary $x_1$) and got $0$.  That is, the integral of a function that is $1$ at one point and $0$ everywhere else is $0$.

Answer (score 0):

You might see [the webpage](https://online.stat.psu.edu/stat414/node/107/) where, quote, "$P[(X,Y)\in A]=\int\int_Af(x,y)dxdy$ where $\{(X,Y)\in A\}$". You area here was $A(\{(X,Y)|X=Y\})=0$. Thus the integral was a finite number multiple by the area $0$, proven the statement.

Comment: No, it's not $\delta(x_1 - x_2)$ (a Dirac delta), it's $1_{x_1 = x_2}$ (i.e. $1$ when $x_1 = x_2$, $0$ otherwise).

Comment: @RobertIsrael deleted, I was thinking too much about Fourier space these days...